# Rich Text Area in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, richtextbox

Do we have any Rich Textbox/Textarea options in MVC3 or do we need to use jquery RichTextbox plugins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC has nothing to do with Rich TextArea. You will need JavaScript/jQuery for it. I would recommend using [jHtmlArea](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/)

Comment: +1 for the link to jHTMLArea. I was looking for an HTML editor for my MVC application that gave client side API for programmatic control on the client side.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use plugins. ASP.NET MVC is a server side framework which allow you to spit HTML. And in HTML you have the `<textarea>` tag. That's where the ASP.NET MVC framework role ends. If you want to make something more out of this textarea tag you need client scripting => so go ahead and pick your favorite WYSIWYG editor. There are lots of them.